# Discord.js User Avatar in Thumbnail

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

Hello I want the user to execute the command. His avatar can be seen in the embed thumbmail.
I use V12

my code

```
client.on("message", async message => {
  let cmd = message
    if (message.content === 'test') {
      if (message.author.bot) return;
      const Embedentwickler = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setColor('#0404B4')
      .setTitle(message.author.username)
      .setAuthor('test')
      .setThumbnail(message.author.avatarURL)
      .setDescription('test'
      .addFields(
        )
      .setTimestamp()
      .setFooter('test');
    
    message.channel.send(Embedentwickler);
}})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`User.avatarURL()` is a method (for some reason), not a property so you should do this:

```
.setThumbnail(message.author.avatarURL())
```